# Activate all Bundles in a Folder

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

i have a Problem. I have to write a CMS in Java and it should be modularized. Bundles should be easily added. For this i thought about using OSGi and it works quite Well. 
The Bundles are in a separate folder named "plugins"

But the Problem is, that i don't know how i can manage the Bundles, that they are installed and activated without manually installed and activated.
This should happen at runtime, without restarting the Server.

I guess there is a solution for my problem, but i don't know how and i didn't find anything helpfull while i googled. Please Help me. If you need more Information please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several projects that do this logic. One of the most commonly used: http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-file-install.html